# How to maximum height and body to move in projectile motion( on Canvas)

Tags: java, android

[image]

**Really.anybody Know't this question's Answer? **

I asked this question before, but I think I worded it badly and thus did not get any response. I am trying to use an projectile motion in my game. It works. But Canvas coordinate system to Left Top corner to calculate. So projectile point is inverted. I don't know how to maximum height and body to move in point.
please help me. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
public class strak extends View {

public float x;
public float y;
private Controller controller;
private ProjectileEquation projectileEquation;
public int trajectoryPointCount = 20;
public float timeSeparation = 1/3f;

float x1, x2, y1, y2;
private Bitmap bmp;

public static class ProjectileEquation {


    public float gravity;
    public Vector2 startVelocity = new Vector2();
    public Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2();

    public float getX(float t) {
        return startPoint.x + t * startVelocity.x;
    }

    public float getY(float t) {

        return 0.5f * gravity * t * t + startVelocity.y * t + startPoint.y;
    }
}

public static class Controller {
    public float power = 10f;
    public float angle = 0f;
}

public strak(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.controller = new Controller();
    this.projectileEquation = new ProjectileEquation();
    this.projectileEquation.gravity = 10f;
    Log.i("BitmapFactory", "Create!");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.boll);
    yyyyyy();
}

private void yyyyyy() {
    projectileEquation.startVelocity.set( controller.power,0f);
    projectileEquation.startVelocity.rotate(controller.angle);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        x2 = ev.getX();
        y2 = ev.getY();

        invalidate(); 

     long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000.000f;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        if((y1 < y2 )&& (x1 < x2)){

            controller.angle-= .2* deltaTime;
            controller.power-= .2* deltaTime;
            Log.i("LOG_TAG,", "Right to Down Cros");
        }
        if((y1 > y2 )&& (x1 > x2)){
            controller.angle+= .2* deltaTime;
            controller.power+= .2* deltaTime;
            Log.i("LOG_TAG,", "Down to Right Cros");
        }
        if((y1 > y2 )&& (x1 < x2)){
            controller.angle+= .2* deltaTime;
            controller.power+= .2* deltaTime;
            Log.i("LOG_TAG,", "Down to Left Cros");
        }
        if((y1 < y2 )&& (x1 > x2)){
            controller.angle-= .2* deltaTime;
            controller.power-= .2* deltaTime;
            Log.i("LOG_TAG,", "Left to  Down Cros");
        }
                switch (ev.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.i("LOG_TAG,", "ACTION_MOVE:");
        x1 = ev.getX();
        y1 = ev.getY();
                }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    yyyyyy();
    float t = 0f;
    x = getWidth() / 2;
    y = getHeight()/2;
    float timeSeparation = this.timeSeparation;

    for (int i = 0; i < trajectoryPointCount; i++) {
        float x = this.x + projectileEquation.getX(t);
        float y = this.y + projectileEquation.getY(t);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
        t += timeSeparation;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No one answers because we don't understand what you need, and your code is quite unclean, so no one wants to take a plunge and understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: fast sorry sar. I want a parabola on my Canvas. but Canvas calculate coordinate system to Left Top corner.so I want Draw Left Bottom.

Comment: `yToDaw = canvas.height - computedY`?

Comment: Yes sar.Right...

Comment: but .how to do set

Answer (score -2):

You could try to do a symmetry with respect to x axis, like this:

```
float y = -(this.y + projectileEquation.getY(t));
```